# Can we extend a function from the diagonal matrices to an orthogonally-invariant function on $\text{GL}_n$?

Tags: gn.general-topology, lie-groups, symmetric-functions, orthogonal-groups, singular-values

This is a [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3631207/extending-a-function-from-the-positive-diagonal-matrices-to-orthogonally-invaria).

Let $g:(0,\infty)^n \to [0,\infty)$ be a symmetric function -i.e. $g(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n)$ does not depend on the order of the $\sigma_i$, with $g(1,\dots,1)=0$.

We identify $(0,\infty)^n$ with the space $\text{PDiag}$ of real positive-definite diagonal $n \times n$ matrices.

> **Question:** Does there exist a function $f:\text{PDiag} \times \text{GL}_n^+ \to\mathbb R^{\ge 0}$
>   satisfying
>   $$  \,\,\,\,f(\tilde \Sigma,U\Sigma V)= f(\Sigma,U^{-1}\tilde  \Sigma V^{-1}) \, \, \text{ for every } \, U,V \in \text{SO}_n \, \, \text{and } \Sigma, \tilde \Sigma \in \text{PDiag},
> \text{ and }\,\,   \, \, f(\Sigma,\text{Id})=g(\Sigma)$$

Also, If we assume that $g$ is continuous, can we create a continuous extension $f$?

(Here $\text{GL}_n^+ $ refers to the group of real invertible $n \times n$ matrices with positive determinant).

If that matters, I am ready to replace $\text{SO}_n $ with $\text{O}_n $ and assume "bi-$\text{O}_n$-invariance" in the first requirement instead of "bi-$\text{SO}_n$-invariance".

Comment: It seems to me that only trivial functions can satisfy your invariance property. Or perhaps you  made a typo wrt $\Sigma$ and $\widetilde{\Sigma}.$

Comment: Hi, I am not sure why you think that. My "inspiration" comes from bi-SO(n)-invariant distances; You can take $f$ to be the restriction of such a distance on $GL \times GL$, and $g(\Sigma)$ to be the distance of $\Sigma$ from the identity matrix. Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: If $g$ factors through $\det$ then $f(a,b)$ can be $g(a)+g(b)$, $g(a)g(b)$, $|g(a)-g(b)|$.... I'm not sure this is the only $g$ for which you can find $f$ but proving it looks like a dive into linear algebra because you need to understand eigenvalues of $U\Sigma V$ and $U^{-1}\tilde  \Sigma V^{-1}$ for all $U, V$. You could use some CAS to see if there is any algebraic relation in low dimensions ($2 \le n \le 5$).